# Project targets unsupported platform

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a Visual Studio solution with several projects in it.  I am trying to get the core project to build and I am getting the following error:

*"The project targets or references an unsupported platform: .NETPlatform,Version=v5.0. Applied.Hosted.Core"*

I did some googling and found a result that made me believe that I need to add the following to the project.json file.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
 }
```

My project does not have a project.json file.  This is some work that I have taken over from a former employee.  Can someone lead me in the right direction?  There is a packages.config file.  Do I need to reference dnxcore50 in packages.config?

Comment: The `project.json` project format is a very old format. It was only shipped by Microsoft in an RC level and then completely abandoned. `.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0` sounds like the pre-release name for what has now become .NET Core. Based on these two thoughts, I think this is a really really old piece of code that uses technologies that are no longer supported. You will probably have to migrate to newer (supported) techologies piece by piece. Is there a `.csproj` file in this project? If not, what project format does it use?

Comment: @omajid There is a .csproj file in the project.  I see from the .csproj file that the TargetFramework is 4.5.2.  Maybe one of the dll's the project references is .NET Core.  The only reference I see in the .csproj file that mentions netcore is the following:

<Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\CommonServiceLocator.1.3\lib\portable-net4+sl5+netcore45+wpa81+wp8\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>

Comment: I would reccommend reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/ and the subpages. I think the current approach is this: if this is a library, port it to .NET Framework 4.62, then to `netstandard2.0`. Then this library can be consumed by .NET Framework and .NET Core projects. But definitely read the porting docs through a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks @omajid.  I noticed the ServiceLocation was not used in the project that referenced it.  Maybe the previous developer was going to use it.  I removed the reference and the build succeeded.  I will read the documents you suggested regardless.