# PostSharp Error - The project targets or references an unsupported platform: .NETPlatform,Version=v5.0

Tags: postsharp, .net-4.7.2

I'm using *PostSharp v5.0.48* in quite a few projects that target .NETFramework 4.7.2 (both console apps and libraries).

[image: Current project target framework and output type]

[image: Target framework in project file]

[image: Target framework in packages.config]

[image: PostSharp properties - left as default as with all other versions I've used]

I recently attempted to update to *PostSharp v6.4.4* yesterday which gave me the error noted below.  I then noticed *v6.4.5* was released overnight so I upgraded to that in hopes of it eliminating the error but nothing; still receiving the same error message.

> ...\packages\PostSharp.6.4.5\build\PostSharp.targets(379,5): error PS0275: The project targets or references an unsupported platform: .NETPlatform,Version=v5.0.

I have also installed the newest *PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio* from [here](https://www.postsharp.net/downloads/postsharp-6.4/v6.4.5/PostSharp-6.4.5.exe)

I'm at a loss here as I'm clearly targeting .NETFramework v4.7.2.  Any help/ideas are appreciated.

- Note #1: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522720/project-targets-unsupported-platform) post but it was of no help as it was made by a former employee of mine but under very different circumstances and a completely different situation.
- Note #2: Downgrading back to the highest version in v5.x has eliminated the error (currently using *v5.0.55*) but if I go one version higher, *v6.0.18*, the error returns.

Comment: That's the kind of platform moniker you'd get in a Xamarin project or library.  [Not supported](https://doc.postsharp.net/whats-new-50#xamarin).

Comment: Well, this isn't a Xamarin library; just a standard .NETFramwork library.

Comment: That's not what the moniker says.  Bill Greer had the exact same problem, whatever he did to work around it did not solve the core issue.  Getting the moniker wrong is very unusual, hard to have a guess at it without seeing the detailed build trace.  Try another machine, especially so if this fails on the machine that the "former employee" used.

Comment: Bill was working on a completely different project.  This has nothing to do with what his question asked.

Comment: Bill was also working a project that used PostSharp v5.0.48 which me and my team have been using for well over a year without issue.  This is a different project, situation, context, everything.

Comment: @Sandon This usually means that PostSharp was unable to identify a target framework of an assembly. It can be caused by incorrect integration with MSBuild or simply that there was some strange reference that couldn't be identified correctly (it may happen for some PCL profiles). If the problem occurs after upgrading to the current version, it'd best to report it on PostSharp's support. Please include msbuild diagnostic log (`-v:diag` switch) and also enable assembly binding trace with `-p:PostSharpTrace=AssemblyBinder` switch.

Comment: Hmm, that could make sense as we just recently updated all of our projects from Framework 4.5.2 to Framework 4.7.2 (plan to switch to Core and Standard soon but I'm bwing held up due to the environments we deploy to). Appreciate the suggestion. I was planning on opening a support ticket with PostSharp when I get back from holiday vacation if nothing came from this post here so it looks like I'll do that for sure. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm still unsure of the exact cause of the issue but it appears that updating to v6.4.7 has eliminated the issue.